# Square Payment form CSS issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ejs, square

I’m adding the Square payment form to an existing ejs file. Once I add the square html to the page, my Bootstrap navigation bar anchor tags no longer work, but only on the anchor tags in the middle of the navigation bar. The outside links work. The dropdown menu also becomes disabled when the Square form is added. If I comment out the Square form, the navigation bar functionality returns to normal and so do the anchor tags.

I’ve tried adding a div around the navigation bar and also around the Square payment form, but to no avail. I’ve also tried adding padding in the CSS to all of the elements, but same results. Could it be the behavior of the iframe being triggered by the Square javascript file? Is it perhaps fighting with Bootstrap?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Friends of Roam</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/mission">Our Mission<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="https://tranquil-caverns-74813.herokuapp.com/">Roam Music School</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/communityOutreach">Community Outreach</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/successStories">Success Stories</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/board">Our Board Members</a>
      </li>

     <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact Us</a>
      </li>

        <br>

      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/square">Donate Today</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>


<h2 class ="text-center">Thank you for supporting the arts in our community!</h1>

<div id="form-container">
  <div id="sq-ccbox">

    <form id="nonce-form" novalidate action="PATH/TO/PAYMENT/PROCESSING/PAGE" method="post">
      <fieldset>
        <span class="label">Card Number</span>
        <div id="sq-card-number"></div>

        <div class="third">
          <span class="label">Expiration</span>
          <div id="sq-expiration-date"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="third">
          <span class="label">CVV</span>
          <div id="sq-cvv"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="third">
          <span class="label">Postal</span>
          <div id="sq-postal-code"></div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>

      <button id="sq-creditcard" class="button-credit-card" onclick="requestCardNonce(event)">Donate $1.00</button>

      <div id="error"></div>

      <input type="hidden" id="card-nonce" name="nonce">
    </form>
  </div> <!-- end #sq-ccbox -->

</div> <!-- end #form-container -->
```

CSS:

```
* {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

body, html {
  color: #373F4A;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
}


iframe {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

button {
  border: 0;
}

hr {
  height: 1px;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #CCC;
}

fieldset {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

h2 {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

/*.navbar {*/
/*  padding-bottom: 10px;*/
/*}*/

#form-container {
  padding-top: 400px;
  position: relative;
  width: 380px;
  margin: auto;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.label {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.third {
  float: left;
  width: calc((100% - 32px) / 3);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 16px 16px 0;
}

.third:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 0;
}

/* Define how SqPaymentForm iframes should look */
.sq-input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #E0E2E3;
  border-radius: 4px;
  outline-offset: -2px;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: border-color .2s ease-in-out, background .2s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: border-color .2s ease-in-out, background .2s ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition: border-color .2s ease-in-out, background .2s ease-in-out;
          transition: border-color .2s ease-in-out, background .2s ease-in-out;
}

#sq-ccbox {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

/* Define how SqPaymentForm iframes should look when they have focus */
.sq-input--focus {
  border: 1px solid #4A90E2;
  background-color: rgba(74,144,226,0.02);
}


/* Define how SqPaymentForm iframes should look when they contain invalid values */
.sq-input--error {
  border: 1px solid #E02F2F;
  background-color: rgba(244,47,47,0.02);
}

#sq-card-number {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

/* Customize the "Donate with Credit Card" button */
.button-credit-card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 56px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: #4A90E2;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: background .2s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: background .2s ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition: background .2s ease-in-out;
          transition: background .2s ease-in-out;
}

.button-credit-card:hover {
  background-color: #22F022;
}


#error {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 16px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem was that the Square payment form's CSS was set to margin:auto;

When I added the margin to the top and sides individually, the problem went away.

```
#form-container {
  margin-top: 150px;
  position: relative;
  width: 380px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

The second problem with the drop-down menu was that I hadn't included the Bootstrap JS cdn in the head.

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```